# How to use a built-in in another built-in for Open policy agent

Tags: go, open-policy-agent, rego

Is there a way to call a built-in (like io.jwt.decode_verify(string, constraints)) in a new built-in that I wanted to create?

Or is there a way to call OPA's internal package's method?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the exported built-ins from the `topdown.GetBuiltin` functions. In the example below the `base64.encode` function is called from the `my_custom` custom built-in:

```golang
    rego.RegisterBuiltin2(
        &rego.Function{
            Name:    "my_custom",
            Decl:    types.NewFunction(types.Args(types.S), types.A),
        },
        func(bctx rego.BuiltinContext, a, b *ast.Term) (*ast.Term, error) {
            b64encode := topdown.GetBuiltin("base64.encode")
            if b64encode == nil {
                panic("base64.encode missing")
            }

            var res *ast.Term
            if err := b64encode(bctx, []*ast.Term{a}, func(encoded *ast.Term) error {
                res = encoded
                return nil
            }); err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }

            return res, nil
        },
    )
```